# WPF datagrid - cell updated based on antother cell value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell

I'd like to ask because I am struggling with this issue for hours.

I implemented a datagrid and want to populate "Height of spring point" (TextBox) based on selected "SP Type" (ComboBox) within same row.

[datagrid row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yE4p.png)

Value is populated, but not shown, I have to click to "Height of spring point" cell and only then a value is shown. I have already tried UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus istead of UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, did not work.

SelectedPbType property includes function for retrieving desired value which should be shown immediately after SP Type is chosen.

Sorry for naming mismatch. SP Type means PB Type.

Could you please have a look and tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

View:

```
<dg:DataGrid Height="330" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,0,0" 
                x:Name="autocadCoordinationsDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="25" ColumnWidth="Auto" 
                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                Background="#e6ecff" 
                BorderBrush="Gray" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                CanUserAddRows="false"
                     CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                     CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding CadCoordinates}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCadCoordinate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="cbTempPbType" Header="{lex:Loc EnvironmentCoordinatesGridColumnPbType}" Width="SizeToHeader" >
                    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbPbType" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PbTypes}}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPbType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPbType.Index}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Index">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionPbTypeChangedCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <dg:DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{lex:Loc EnvironmentCoordinatesGridColumnPillarsHeight}" 
                    Width="SizeToHeader"
                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}"
                    Binding="{Binding PillarsHeight,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" >
                    <dg:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        </Style>
                    </dg:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </dg:DataGridTextColumn>

            </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Model:

```
public class CadCoordinatesGrid : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler Changed;
    private EnvironmentViewModel _viewModel;

    public CadCoordinatesGrid()
    {

    }

    public CadCoordinatesGrid(EnvironmentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PbType> _pbType;
    public ObservableCollection<PbType> PbType
    {
        get
        {
            return _pbType;
        }
        set
        {
            _pbType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PbType");
        }
    }

    private PbType _selectedPbType;
    public PbType SelectedPbType
    {
        get
        {

            return _selectedPbType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_viewModel != null) _viewModel.IsDirty = true;

            this.PillarsHeight = EnvironmentHelper.GetPillarHeightFrom(value);
            //OnPropertyChanged("PillarsHeight");

            _selectedPbType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPbType");
        }
    }

    private string _pillarsHeight;
    public string PillarsHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return _pillarsHeight;
        }
        set
        {
            CommonHelper.TryParseDecimal(value);

            if (_viewModel != null) _viewModel.IsDirty = true;
            _pillarsHeight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => PillarsHeight);
        }
    }

    private ICommand selectionPbTypeChangedCommand;
    public ICommand SelectionPbTypeChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectionPbTypeChangedCommand == null)
            {
                selectionPbTypeChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.PbTypeChangeSelected(),
                    null);
            }
            return selectionPbTypeChangedCommand;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the selected.
    /// </summary>
    private void PbTypeChangeSelected()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(()=> this.PillarsHeight);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [property changed].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var hander = this.Changed;
        if (hander != null)
        {
            hander(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the setter of the `SelectedPbType` property that sets the `PillarsHeight` property.

Get rid of the interaction trigger and the SelectedValue binding and the SelectedValuePath of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbPbType" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PbTypes}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPbType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ComboBox>
```

You should not bind both the SelectedItem and SelectedValue properties of the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it did not help. And you are correct, SelectedPbType sets PillarsHeight property.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a minimal and reproducible sample then?: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Get rid of all unnecessary and irrelevant base classes, types, static resources, etc. Setting the source property that the DataGridTextColumn is bound to should work.

Comment: It is not necessary anymore, it works now, I went through the code and removed unnecessary code, you gave me an idea, thank you very much